# Execute a dynamic asp button click event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've create a dashboard that contains multiple dynamic buttons. When I click the "Delete" button I want the server side code to execute. I've added the code to the Click event handler of my button.

The dynamic button is created with the following code:

```
Button PopupDeleteButton = new Button();
PopupDeleteButton.ID = "PBD" + controlValue.ID.ToString();
PopupDeleteButton.Text = "Delete";
PopupDeleteButton.Style["Height"] = "15px";
PopupDeleteButton.Style["Width"] = "50px";
PopupDeleteButton.Style["top"] = "0";
PopupDeleteButton.Style["right"] = "0";
PopupDeleteButton.Style["float"] = "left";
PopupDeleteButton.Style["font-size"] = "9px";
PopupDeleteButton.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.VerticalAlign, "top");
PopupDeleteButton.Attributes.Add("runat","server");             
PopupDeleteButton.Click += new EventHandler(this.RemoveWidgetFromXML_Click);
```

However when the I click the dynamic button on the form a post back occurs, and the function RemoveWidgetFromXML is never called. Any ideas? I've looked all over Google but can't find how to stop the post-back from occurring prior to the event call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to recreate dynamic control on every page postback. In that case event handler will be called.